# How I do to open keyboard in my app when I click in the label?,to put numbers)

Tags: android

I am creating one app for solve quadratic equations, this app is for a work to school. I am very estressed because I don't knkow how start. I am a aficionated and I work hard but I have a lot of doubts. One this is How I  do to  open  keyboard in my app when I click in the label?

Comment: you don't put number to label it's need edittext!

Comment: Then why there is **EditText** , why you want to use label ? any specific reason

Comment: What people are trying to say is: use `EditText` to receive input.

Comment: not sorry is a EditText

Comment: @user2509070 Sorry, but it's hard to understand you. Are you saying you have an EditText? Then the keyboard should already be shown when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an EditText, and the input will be handled automatically.

You can get the text with `yourEditText.getText().toString();` in your Activity

Don´t forget to define your EditText there (in *OnCreate()*) first:

`EditText yourEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.youredittext);`

(*youredittext* is the id of your EditText in your XML-Layout)

Comment: Ok, but in the AVD I don't have keyboard